# QtScript can't call function with argument type "QString &"

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qtscript

I got below error

```
"TypeError: cannot call sayHello(): argument 2 has unknown type `QString&' (register the type with qScriptRegisterMetaType())"
```

when execute my Qt program test.exe to call a javascrip file haha.js. What I was trying to do is to return a value ("result") from "void sayHello(const QString &name, QString &result);" in javascript. Looks like QtScript understands (const QString &) but can't understand (QString &). Any idea what I did wrong?

haha.js

```
h = new Haha();
result = "";
h.sayHello("henry", result);
result;
```

the Qt program consists: haha.h, haha.cpp, main.cpp

haha.h

```
#ifndef HAHA_H
#define HAHA_H

#include <QObject>

class Haha : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Haha(QObject *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void sayHello(const QString &name, QString &result);
};

#endif // HAHA_H
```

haha.cpp

```
#include "haha.h"

Haha::Haha(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void Haha::sayHello(const QString &name, QString &result)
{
    result = "Hello " + name;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QtScript>

#include "haha.h"

Q_SCRIPT_DECLARE_QMETAOBJECT(Haha, QObject*)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QScriptEngine engine;
    QScriptValue HahaClass = engine.scriptValueFromQMetaObject<Haha>();
    engine.globalObject().setProperty("Haha", HahaClass);

    QString fileName = "haha.js";
    QFile scriptFile(fileName);
    if (!scriptFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        return -1;
    }
    QTextStream b(&scriptFile);
    QString contents = b.readAll();
    scriptFile.close();

    QScriptValue result = engine.evaluate(contents, fileName);
    qDebug()<<result.toString();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your original question has 2 sub-questions:

Q1. How to avoid the above runtime error?

Q2. How to return multiple data from C++ to QML?

A1. It appears that QML does not recognize well C++ reference symbol `&`, and this does not matter whether you use `const` or not. So if you use the following version:

```
void sayHelloV2(const QString name, QString result);
```

the runtime error will go away. More precisely, QML does allow the first argument to be a C++ reference, so the following version can also avoid the runtime error:

```
void sayHelloV3(const QString &name, QString result);
```

This is a mystery to me as well. Maybe Qt framework developers can explain us why.

A2. If you want multiple data to be returned from C++ to QML, one solution is to use QVariantMap as the function's return type, as shown in the following version:

```
QVariantMap sayHelloV4(const QString name, QString result);
```

Inside your C++ return value, you can insert as many data as needed. (name, result, etc.). But your QML code has to post-process the return value to get the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your second argument has `QString&` type, but it should be `const QString&`.

Comment: for the 2nd argument, I intended to use "QString &" so that I can pass in a QString and get result from calling "void sayHello(const QString &name, QString &result)"

Comment: Use `QString sayHello(const QString& name)` to return a value from the function.

Comment: but I do want the sayHello() to return both an error code and a value. Is there a way to make (QString &) work?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on JavaScript. But after google "return value through parameters in javascript" and "return multiple values in javascript". But I didn't find the standard myself.

I think your way to have return value in parameter is impossible. Then `QString&` is no meaning here.

Hope others could teach or correct me on this topic, thanks.

Comment: I've posted another question to ask about how to return value from JavaScript at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438475/possible-to-return-a-value-from-javascript-function-parameter , they gave me 2 ways to solve my problem. You can check the details there.

Answer (score 0):

The data conversion between js and Qt data type is done by QScriptValue, basically this means the QString in the slot is not the js string you passed in.

Passing a reference cannot do the magic, just think about some other way.

For example, you can add a function that returns the last error.

Comment: so you mean there's no way to return a value from function parameter?